# Minecraft and java troubles

Tags: java, intel-graphics, minecraft, opengl

I like to play Minecraft. But recently I can only be able to open Minecraft versions that is lower than 1.7.2. When I launch 1.7.2 the Minecraft didn't show that I have to upgrade the card. My OpenGL version is 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3 and OpenGL ES is 2.0 Mesa 10.1.3. It seems like it's not a problem with cards or any hardware (maybe it is because I changed my HDD to another computer). I've tried launching Minecraft through Oracle Java 7, Oracle Java 8 and OpenJDK Java 7. Here is the log:

```
[16:55:52 INFO]: Job 'Version & Libraries' finished successfully (took 0:01:15.420)
[16:55:52 INFO]: Launching game
[16:55:52 INFO]: Unpacking natives to /home/diamond/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1-natives-1665154416894
[16:55:52 INFO]: Launching in /home/diamond/.minecraft
[16:55:52 INFO]: Half command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=/home/diamond/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1-natives-1665154416894 -cp /home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-core-mojang/51.2/icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/codecjorbis/20101023/codecjorbis-20101023.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/codecwav/20101023/codecwav-20101023.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/libraryjavasound/20101123/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/librarylwjglopenal/20100824/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/soundsystem/20120107/soundsystem-20120107.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.23.Final/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput/2.0.5/jinput-2.0.5.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/jutils/jutils/1.0.0/jutils-1.0.0.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/authlib/1.5.17/authlib-1.5.17.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/realms/1.7.8/realms-1.7.8.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.0-beta9/log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.0-beta9/log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.1/lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.1/lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/libraries/tv/twitch/twitch/6.5/twitch-6.5.jar:/home/diamond/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main
[16:55:52 INFO]: Looking for orphaned versions to clean up...
[16:55:53 ERROR]: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
[16:55:53 ERROR]: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
A bunch of Stream Closed later (about 30 I guess)
[16:55:53 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
[16:55:53 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[16:55:53 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...
[16:55:53 INFO]: Deleting /home/diamond/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1-natives-1665154416894
```

And what shows in the Game Output is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
```

Can anyone help me?

Hardware specs:

- CPU: 2x Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4200 @ 2.00GHz
- Memory: 1979MB or 2GB
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS running xubuntu-desktop
- OpenGL renderer: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel GM45 Express Chipset
- OpenGL vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Chipset
- X11 Vendor: The X.Org Foundation 1.15.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a terminal and enter this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(One line at a time)

You may need to reenable unity's opengl using `compizconfig-settings-manager`, so after that execute `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

After you did this type in `ccsm` and under the Desktop section go to the ubuntu unity plugin and reactivate it.

As for the other error, you may need to remove your `~/.minecraft` subdirectory.

**WARNING! YOU WILL LOSE ALL YOUR SAVES/SERVERS, BACK THEM UP BEFOREHAND, SAME GOES FOR MODS. THIS WILL RESET MINECRAFT TO STOCK**

Comment: Glad to see that but I'm not using Unity. I'm using Xubuntu session or xubuntu-desktop to play. And I have also disabled Composite in it's setting.

Comment: Oh, then just remove ~/.minecraft, using 'rm -rf ~/.minecraft'

Comment: Still the same problem but I'll try the repo. Before that I've tried sgfxi to update so... Oh and I enabled Composite in Xubuntu because as I remember in Compiz that enabling Composite requires OpenGL so that would be fine I guess... BTW What Window Manager does XFCE uses?

Comment: What I want to say now is after removing .minecraft the amount of Stream Closed decreased xD

Comment: OH WOW After I removed .minecraft, run it with Oracle Java 8, edit the arguments from -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode to -XX:-CMSIncrementalMode. Have to run it by Java 8 BTW.